# Rails: 'require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and I have installed Ruby 2.2.2, Rails 4.2.3, Gem version 2.4.8, DevKit, a MySQL server, and it says that I have successfully installed the MySQL2 gem, however, when I go to the root directory of my web app and use the `rails server` command, I get the following error:

[image]

I reinstalled all of the programs (Ruby, Rails, MySQL2, DevKit, etc.) and I am still prompted with this error.

(P.S. I know that other people have posted this same problem but I couldn't find a solution that worked)

Thanks.